# How to convert PHP variable to its real value?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-4.2

How can I convert my `{{ $user_count }}` as its real value (e.g. 543) and return it in the view?

**UsersController.php**: (My controller is successfully getting the count of users)

```
public function userCount(){
    $user_count = //Rest of the code to count the row users in the database table
    return View::make('data', compact('user_count');  //$user_count holds the number of users
}
```

=========================================================================

**index.blade.php:** (I have a jquery in here.)

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
 <div id="user_count"></div>
 <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){

            $.ajax({
                url: "{{asset('../app/views/data.blade.php')}}",
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'html',

            }).done(function(data){
                $('#user_count').html(data);
            });

    });
 </script>
```

=========================================================================

**data.blade.php** (Get the data from the controller)

```
{{ $user_count }}
```

When I tried the page `/data` page, the number of users appear, but when I call it in the ajax request the output is *plain text* like this:

```
{{ $user_count }}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are another solution, I think more easy:

```
<span>Total Users: {{ Users::count() }}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful how you call the ajax php page :)

You said:

> When I tried the page /data page, the number of users appear,

But, on you code, you have:

```
url: "{{asset('../app/views/data.blade.php')}}",
```

On your code, this is an **asset** URL. This means a direct url to the .php file.
You should link the url to the controller, controller that will call and generate the view.

**Solution:** use the real url to the controller.

```
url: "{{ url('yourobject/yoursuperroute')}}",
```

Example:

```
url: "/data",
```